# × TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to build a simple counter using React and Redux but I am stuck with this error. The error comes up on line 23, that is `const store=createStore(reducer)`. The React version I am using is 16.8.6.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'react';
import {connect,Provider} from 'react-redux';
import './styles.scss';

const InitialState = {
  count: 0,
};

const IncrementValue = () => ({
  type: 'INCREMENT',
});

const reducer = (state = InitialState, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'INCREMENT') {
    return {
      count: state.count + 1,
    };
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(reducer);

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { count, increment } = this.props;
    console.log({ count, increment });
    return (
      <main className="Counter">
        <p className="count">0</p>
        <section className="controls">
          <button>Increment</button>
          <button>Decrement</button>
          <button>Reset</button>
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
const mapStatetoProps = state => {
  return state;
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    increment() {
      dispatch(IncrementValue());
    },
  };
};
const CounterContainer=connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <CounterContainer/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[createStore](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore) is a function of Redux, not React.
Change import to

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
```